# styles in bundle / app css creates from the deepest child to root parent (from the end to the beginning order)

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack

The first problem was with not working reset.css that when i import "gloabal.scss" in App or index.js, it has reset.css and other global settings, such as fonts grid containers etc. which should be overwrtiiten if needed by child components, but it cant be done cause of css cascade. i solve it by addtional chunk for css, but i think the problem is still not solved, because if i expect to change smth parent styles from children, i cant do it
simple example structure:

index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import router from "@router";

import { store } from '@store';

import App from '@components/App'
import '@scss/global.scss'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

new Vue({
el: '#app',
render: h => h(App),
router,
 store
});
```

Then in App.vue is importing Menu.vue with menu.css and in menu is importing product.vue as well

webpack config:

````
```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = (env) => {
return {
    mode: env.production ? 'production' : 'development',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
    // devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        clean: true
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
            { test: /\.vue$/, use: [{ loader: 'vue-loader', options: { hotReload: 
     env.development } 
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-resources-loader', options: {
                            resources: [
                                path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/variables.scss'),
                                path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/mixins.scss'),
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: env.production,
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 1
                },
                styles: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /[\\/]src[\\/]assets[\\/]scss[\\/]/,
                    name: 'global',
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 0
                },
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
        }),
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css'
        }),
        new SpriteLoaderPlugin(),
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],

    devServer: { port: '3000', historyApiFallback: true, hot: true }
    }
}
````

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
"css-loader": "^6.2.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.2.0",
"sass": "^1.37.5",
"sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
"sass-resources-loader": "^2.2.4",
"svg-sprite-loader": "^6.0.9",
"vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
"webpack": "^5.49.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
},
"dependencies": {
 "reset-css": "^5.0.1",
 "vue": "^2.6.14",
 "vue-fragment": "^1.5.2",
 "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
 "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
 "vuex": "^3.6.2"
}
```

result / bundle.css : product , menu, app

````
.product {
  width: 300px;
}
.menu .test {
  background: red;
  padding: 100px;
}
.app {
  width: 50px;
}
```
````

I am expecting: app -> menu -> product css, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `import '@scss/global.scss'` needs to be at the top of the file. You import it after your `components/App.vue` which results in the styles being included after the component styles. Webpack doesn't know how you want to order the css, so you must order it yourself.

Comment: its ok about global css i put it into single chunk anyway. main problem about bundle css and reverted nesting